# Ubuntu 12.04 and Nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, hdmi

Ever since upgrading to 12.04 64bit, I have a problem with my GTX 570 card. I use my HDTV as a computer monitor and have it connected via HDMI cable. In the nvidia settings, I would always uncheck/untick the "force gpu scaling" because if I didn't, my videos would drop fps in VLC with GPU acceleration enabled. With 11.10, I didn't have any problem with this, but with 12.04, once I uncheck "force gpu scaling", the entire GUI gets blurry and shaky. This is with the 295.40 and the latest 295.49 drivers.

Thanks in advance for anyone that can help.

Comment: 12.04 is EOL. Nvidia, Linux and Ubuntu have all changed since question was asked 5+ years ago. Also OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years and there are no answers or comments. VTC as `not reproducible`.